# Upload raster to PostGIS problem: ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near

Tags: raster2pgsql

I used this command:
`raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M T31TEJ_20210216T104019_B01.tif -F -t 100x100 public.testraster | PGPASSWORD=1122 psql -d ter -h localhost -U dtn -p 5432`
On MacOS Bigsur 11.2.3 it works very good. But, when I deploy to Ubuntu 20.04 It gives the error: ERROR:  `unterminated quoted string at or near "'010000` and `free(): invalid pointer`.

Can you help me?

I configured the PostGIS like on Mac.

[image: Error]

Here is the extensions which was installed.

[image: Extensions]

Comment: Shot on the dark, but you *may* be hitting the bash maximum argument character length when piping SQL `INSERT` commands directly to `psql` (`getconf MAX_ARG_STRLEN`). Pipe to file using the `COPY` protocol commands (`-Y` flag), then try the import from that file. You can also try reducing tile size.

Comment: ...and I hope that's a dummy password you posted up there. On the internet. If not you'd better say yes and change it ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, this password just ASAP :D. I uninstalled the postgres and posgis then reinstalled, it work now. I think I forgot to install GDAL Driver on postgres, maybe.